# Logistic Regression bootstrapping gives 0 bias and standard error

Tags: r, regression, logistic, bootstrap

I'm an R newbie and I'm trying to use logistic regression to predict Admission granted using 4 dependent variables - GPA, Gender, International student or not and SOP grade. Since I have only 113 data points, I used bootstrap.

```
  logit.bootstrap <- function(d, indices,formula) {
  d<-d[indices,]
  fit <- glm(Admission.Granted ~ GPA + Gender + International.student + 
  CLIgrade, data = data, family = "binomial")
  return(coef(fit))
}

library(boot)
logit.boot <- boot(data=data,sim = "parametric", statistic=logit.bootstrap, R=5000, formula= Admission.Granted ~ GPA + Gender + International.student + CLIgrade)
logit.boot
```

The result I get has only 0 in Bias and Standard Error field. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
PARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = data, statistic = logit.bootstrap, R = 5000, sim = "parametric", 
    formula = Admission.Granted ~ GPA + Gender + International.student + 
        CLIgrade)


Bootstrap Statistics :
      original  bias    std. error
t1*  1.5397795       0           0
t2*  0.5898814       0           0
t3*  0.1148014       0           0
t4* -0.8985390       0           0
t5* -0.1141786       0           0
```

My original logistic Regression summary is as below:

```
Call:
glm(formula = Admission.Granted ~ GPA + Gender + International.student + 
    CLIgrade, family = binomial, data = trainData)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.2729   0.2912   0.4194   0.5987   0.9952  

Coefficients:
                         Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)                0.8936     5.0611   0.177   0.8599  
GPA                        1.2303     1.4029   0.877   0.3805  
GenderM                   -1.2121     0.7334  -1.653   0.0984 .
International.studentYes  -1.5696     0.7384  -2.126   0.0335 *
CLIgrade                  -0.1678     0.1893  -0.886   0.3754  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 60.542  on 68  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 52.832  on 64  degrees of freedom
AIC: 62.832

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using [parametric bootstrap](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96900/why-use-the-parametric-bootstrap). From the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/boot/versions/1.3-28/topics/boot):

> For the parametric bootstrap it is necessary for the user to specify
> how the resampling is to be conducted. The best way of accomplishing
> this is to specify the function `ran.gen` which will return a simulated
> data set from the observed data set and a set of parameter estimates
> specified in `mle`.

You didn't provide any resampling function, hence the statistics were in each of the iterations calculated on exactly the same data, hence standard errors are zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your logit.bootstrap function, your call to glm passes in “data=data” instead of “data=d” which is the dataset that you’ve permuted.

Comment: Thanks @hreed7! I changed it, but still get the same output. All zeros. :(